# historyApiFallback doesn't work in Webpack dev server

Tags: javascript, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server, html5-history

I use Webpack dev server and [browserHistory in React Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory) to manipulate with urls by HTML5 History API. [historyapifallback-option](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option) does not work in my webpack config file. After refreshing `http://localhost:8080/users` or `http://localhost:8080/products` I got 404.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

var common = {
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    entry: './src/script/index.jsx',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js[x]?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};

if(TARGET === 'dev' || !TARGET) {
    module.exports = merge(common,{
        devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'index.js',
            publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets/'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('dev')
            })
        ]
    });
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
        </div>
        <script src="http://localhost:8090/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8090/assets/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, useRouterHistory, browserHistory, Link} from 'react-router';

class Home extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return <div>
          I am home component
          <Link to="/users" activeClassName="active">Users</Link>
          <Link to="/products" activeClassName="active">Products</Link>
        </div>;
  }
}

class Users extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return <div> I am Users component </div>;
  }
}

class Products extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return <div> I am Products component </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/users" component={Users} type="users"/>
        <Route path="/products" component={Products} type="products"/>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('content'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --port 8090 --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "events": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-mixin": "^3.0.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.8.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to change **devServer** in my config, but it didn't help:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'index.html',
    }
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'index.js',
    }
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'http://localhost:8090/assets',
    }
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'http://localhost:8090/assets/',
    }
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'http://localhost:8090/assets/index.html',
    }
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'http://localhost:8090/assets/index.js',
    }
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'http://localhost:8090/assets/index.js',
    }
},
output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
            publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets/'
},
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I meet the same question today.
let config in webpack.config.js: `output.publicPath` be equal to devServer.historyApiFallback.index and **point out html file route**。my webpack-dev-server version is 1.10.1 and work well. http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option doesn't work, you must point out html file route.

for example

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: 'build',
        filename: 'bundle-main.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback:{
            index:'build/index.html'
        },
    },
};
```

historyApiFallback.index indicate that when url path not match a true file,webpack-dev-server use the file config in historyApiFallback.index to show in browser rather than 404 page. then all things about your route change let your js using react-router do it.

Comment: output: {
  publicPath: '/',
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
 }
In my case , my output path is like this and here historyApi fallback is not working even if i placed  historyApiFallback : { index : '/' }

Comment: @BijayRai I have the same config as yours. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: 其他的配置省略 translated using google translate is "Other configuration omitted".

Answer (score 21):

```
output: {
    ...
    publicPath: "/"
  },
```

Adding public path solved this for me

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem and was only able to fix it using `index: '/'` with webpack 4.20.2

```
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/'
        }
```

Comment: for anyone else using React + latest webpack, this was the only solution which helped listed in thread.

Comment: Using webpack 5, this is the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 10):

There is a very tricky thing going on here!

The 404 can be **two totally different** things below.  You can open the Network tab of Chrome to see if it's the initial request that is 404, or the assets within.

If you are not afraid of terminal, you can also do `curl -v http://localhost:8081/product` to see the actual HTTP response code.

### Case 1: 404 on the initial HTML page

This is the case that set-up with historyFallbackApi is not correct.

Usually just `historyApiFallback: true` should work in `devServer` configs of Webpack. ([source](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback))  Yet, if you happen to have a custom `output` folder, you have to set the `index` property of `historyApiFallback` to the same path, as advised by the other answers on this question like [jsdeveloper's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55703622) or [echzin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207496).

### Case 2: 404 on the assets (e.g. `bundle.js` or `vendor.js`)

This one is quite interesting!

In this case you do actually get the initial HTML (i.e. if you add `view-source:` before your URL to become `view-source:http://localhost:8081/admin`, you see your HTML, and/or `curl` command shows the HTML), but the page doesn't work in the browser.

What **historyApiFallback** does, which might sound like a magic, is literally just setting `req.url` of the Express server to be the `index.html` file, for any incoming GET request within the domain.  ([The main two lines in the Source Code](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/blob/master/lib/index.js#L82-L84))

However, if the path to your assets is relative (e.g. in the view-source, you see `<script src="vendor.js"></script>`) **AND** the path that you are landing is not at the same path-depth as index (e.g. you are trying to load `http://localhost:8081/admin/user/12/summary` while the main server is at `http://localhost:8081/admin`), what happens is it cannot find the .js files for your JavaScript code. (in my case `http://localhost:8081/admin/user/12/vendor.js`)

[image]

Note that whatever router that deals with HTML5 History here (react router or vue router), knows how to initialize the internal path to `document.location.href` upon the initial load.  But, it doesn't know where is the "root" to properly update the assets' path to it. (And maybe it's not even its job, in terms of responsibility.) As a result, the path to assets would be calculated based on the URL's path, not the `index.html`'s path! So, for just `src="vendor.js"` with no absolute `/` prefix, it tries to find `/admin/user/12/vendor.js` instead of `/vendor.js`.

What you need to do here is to make sure the `output` path of your WebPack is **an absolute path** and starts with `/`, so regardless of the landing URL, it would always work.  i.e. it's always `<script src="/vendor.js"></script>` in the HTML source.

To do so, you have to set `output.publicPath` to be an absolute path (with or without domain).  You can verify this via the `view-source:` or `curl` technique above. :)

Comment: This `output.publicPath: '/'` saves my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding that *some* paths work but others don't, you may be falling foul of the "dot rule". Per [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback):

> When using dots in your path (common with Angular), you may need to
> use the `disableDotRule`:
>
> **webpack.config.js**
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   //...
>   devServer: {
>     historyApiFallback: {
>       disableDotRule: true,
>     },
>   },
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ref.: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback

This works with any react-router

You have to add `historyApiFallback: true`

```
module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    context: SRC,
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/assets'),
        stats: 'errors-only',
        open: true,
        port: 8080,
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
...
}
```

Comment: They're using this already by passing in the object where they were trying to use  a specific `index`

Answer (score 0):

For me this setting worked out:

```js
 module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle-main.js'
    },

    devServer: {
    /* Telling the server to fallback to index.html if the route is not found at the backend server */
      historyApiFallback: true,
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In webpack.config.js just add these lines

```
devServer: {
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
   allowedHosts: 'all',
   hot: true
    
  },
```

and add this ->  // prefixes: ["http://your url:8081/"]
it's working perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me. i get `404.html`

```js
devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: "./dist",
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /^\/$/, to: './index.html' },
        { from: /./, to: './404.html' }
      ]
    }
  },
```