# BrowserHistory (react-router v4) returns 404 and historyApiFallback not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4

BrowserHistory (react-router v4) returns 404 and historyApiFallback not working.

So when I go to http://localhost:3000/app I get a 404. I tried the following solutions with no avail... any ideas? I also tried setting historyApiFallback to true and not using a relative path for bundle.js i.e. /static/bundle.js in index.html

[historyApiFallback doesn't work in Webpack dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271062/historyapifallback-doesnt-work-in-webpack-dev-server)
[historyApiFallback doesn't work, for scripts, if you're nested multiple path sections deep](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/216)

**Index.html**

```
    `<script src="bundle.js"></script`>
```

**Webpack output**

```
output: {
 path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
 filename: 'bundle.js',
 publicPath: '/'
},
```

**Webpack devServer**

```
historyApiFallback: { index: 'public/index.html' },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassingly it turns out I hadn't correctly setup my Express server routing. I used the same setup from a tutorial which was based on HashRouter....

I added the following to my server.js and it worked!

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```