# Webpack config: devServer.historyApiFallback and output.publicPath

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Recently I came across the same issue as the [post "historyApiFallback doesn't work in Webpack dev server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271062/historyapifallback-doesnt-work-in-webpack-dev-server).

---

I will first quote the **accepted answer** in that **post**.

Answer:

> I meet the same question today. let config in webpack.config.js:
>   output.publicPath be equal to devServer.historyApiFallback.index and
>   point out html file route.my webpack-dev-server version is 1.10.1 and work well. http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option doesn't work, you must point out html file route.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: 'build',
        filename: 'bundle-main.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback:{
            index:'build/index.html'
        },
    },
};
```

---

I tried to use this answer to fix the problem(set `output.publicPath: 'dist'` and `devServer.historyApiFallback:{index:'dist/index.html'}`)
but somehow it didn't work.

After some search I found this [page](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/). According to the description in the page:

> This section is for everyone who ran into this problem in development
>   using webpack-dev-server.. Just as above, what we need to do it tell
>   Webpack Dev Sever to redirect all server requests to /index.html.
>   There are just two properties in your webpack config you need to set
>   to do this, publicPath and historyApiFallback.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

---

According to the config I modified my `devServer.historyApiFallback` to be `true`, and `output.publicPath` to be `/`.

My webpack config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack")
const path = require("path")
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: "./src/base/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader'
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/base/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
}
```

**Everything seemed working now**.

But I have the puzzle that **I don't know why it's working**.

---

To be specific

1. `devServer.historyApiFallback: true` is clear according to [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback), so I'm not doubt about that part.
2. `output.publicPath:/` is pretty vague for me though.

Question:

1. If I tried to use something like `output.publicPath:/public`, it
   will not work. So why I must use `output.publicPath:/` here?
2. How `output.publicPath:/` can tell webpack-devserver to find the
   right place and server the right `index.html`(which is generated by the
   devserver I believe)?

Sry if it's a bit tedious. I just want to provide some detail.

Comment: thanks for the question and answer

Answer (score 2):

> But I have the puzzle that I don't know why it's working.

**Setting 1**
In `webpack.config.js` the setting

```js
output: {
  ...
  publicPath: '/static1/',
    },
```

tells webpack to embed `'/static1/'` into the  bundle's path in the generated .html file:

```
<script src="/static1/<name>.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can open the generated .html file(s) on disk and see the above  tag with `'/static1/'` prepended to the bundle.

**Setting 2**
This setting:

```js
devServer: {
   publicPath: '/static/',      // different from 'static1' we used above
```

tells webpack-dev-server to create a route handler for the path `/static` and serve resourses e.g. `/static/<name>.bundle.js`. The webpack-dev-server is based on Express which uses route handlers e.g. `app.use(/mypath, ...);` to serve requests.

If now you point a browser to `localhost:8080`, you will see blank screen. Righ-click on it to see Page Source. You will see the above `<script>`tag that makes the browser issue GET request for the bundle using the path `/static1/xxx` that doesn't work because you didn't tell webpack-dev-server to create a route handler for this path. Now type in the browser navigation bar 
`http://localhost:8080/static/<name>.bundle.js` and you will see the internals of your bundle.

Eliminate the discrepancy between `static1` and `static` and the page will render. In your case it works because one setting is set explicitly to `'/'` and the second one defaults to the same value.

**Setting 3**
`historyApiFallback` has a more narrow scope than other two settings because it is used with SPAs only. During the initial rendering a user sees the landing page of the SPA e.g. `/mysample.html`. This is the file with our `<script>` tag shown above. It should be used without any path like `/static` prepended to it:

```js
historyApiFallback: {
  ...
  index: mysample.html,
```

because Setting1 and Setting2 apply to bundles, not to bundle-containing .html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, it was succeeded to solve, having specified a `route`, instead of a path to `index.html`

```
devServer: {
  publicPath: `/myApp`,
  historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites: [
      { from: /\/myApp/, to: `/myApp` }
    ]
  }
}
```